# How to detect if the date field is empty when designing a custom title page template?

Tags: beamer, titles, templates

I am trying to create a custom title page but I am not able to write a macro that detects whether the date field is empty or not. If it is then the `block` of the date entry should simply be bypassed.

[image]

The image above looks weird since the date block title is shown but the actual date is empty. Of course I can manually remove the date block for such case, but I still want this to be done automatically. I also want to know how to determine if some field is empty or not.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}


\usecolortheme{rose}

    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}

\useoutertheme[]{tree}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

    \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.2\paperwidth}

    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}


\title{The Main Title of The Presentation}
\subtitle{Short Title Goes here}
\author{Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh}
\institute{North Dakota State University}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{nothing}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{shape=\bfseries}


% Custome title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \inserttitle
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \large \insertsubtitle
    \end{block}
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
    \begin{block}{Author}
        \insertauthor
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Institute}
        \insertinstitute
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Date}
        \insertdate
    \end{block}
    \vspace{\stretch{5}}
                            }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is truly empty (e.g. if your document contains `\date{}`), then you can test for this with

```
\ifx\insertdate\empty%
\else%
   \begin{block}{Date}
       \insertdate
   \end{block}   
\fi
```

Note that if your document does not contain any `\date` command, the current date wil be shown by default.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}
\useoutertheme[]{tree}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}
\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.2\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}


\title{The Main Title of The Presentation}
\subtitle{Short Title Goes here}
\author{Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh}
\institute{North Dakota State University}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{nothing}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{shape=\bfseries}


% Custome title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \inserttitle
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \large \insertsubtitle
    \end{block}
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
    \begin{block}{Author}
        \insertauthor
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Institute}
        \insertinstitute
    \end{block}
    \ifx\insertdate\empty%
    \else%
       \begin{block}{Date}
           \insertdate
       \end{block}   
    \fi
    \vspace{\stretch{5}}
                            }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer **that works for empty or "white" date**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

% Added code:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddDateBox}{\xdef\mystring{\insertdate}\sbox1{\hbox{\mystring}}\sbox2{\hbox{\space}}\ifdim\wd1=\wd2\relax\else\ifx\insertdate\empty\relax\else\begin{block}{Date}\insertdate\end{block}\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\usecolortheme{rose}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}

\useoutertheme[]{tree}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}

    \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

    \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
    \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.2\paperwidth}

    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}


\title{The Main Title of The Presentation}
\subtitle{Short Title Goes here}
\author{Al-Motasem Aldaoudeyeh}
\institute{North Dakota State University}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{nothing}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{title page}{shape=\bfseries}


% Custome title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \inserttitle
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title page}\usebeamerfont{block title}\usebeamertemplate{block title}
        \large \insertsubtitle
    \end{block}
    \vspace{\stretch{2}}
    \begin{block}{Author}
        \insertauthor
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Institute}
        \insertinstitute
    \end{block}
    \AddDateBox
    \vspace{\stretch{5}}
                            }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```